# Algorithm to distribute N elements into X groups exponentially

Tags: arrays, algorithm, swift, split, distribution

I have 600 elements in an array. I would like to distribute them across 100 groups. Any clues on how could I create an algorithm (function or method) that takes the number of elements (600) and the number of groups (100) and distributes those elements exponentially in such groups.

The idea is to create a game where the difficulty increases. There are 600 enemies and 100 levels. First level will have 2 enemies, second level also 2, third level 3 enemies... level 99 will have 20 enemies.

Input array:

```
var enemies = [
    [enemy1],
    [enemy2],
    [enemy3]
    ...
    ]
```

Output array:

```
var levels = [
   [level1
        [enemy1],
        [enemy2]
    ],
    [level2
        [enemy3],
        [enemy4]
    ],
    [level3
        [enemy4],
        [enemy6],
        [enemy7]
    ],
]
```

Is this even possible to do? Or should I look for other solutions? At this point I think I will do some kind of manual distribution, but I'm curious if this problem is as hard as it seems.

Comment: Seems like a Math problem more then a coding problem to me...

Comment: What does "distributes those elements exponentially" mean to you? I doubt you mean the mathematical meaning of an exponential distribution or exponential.

Comment: You want to have a geometric progression with a known starting and end element, and just need a multiplier. Use the sum of geometric progression to find that.